# How route computer traffic from specific NIC card

Tags: networking, system, file-transfer, network-traffic

I have two computers (A & B with WINdows 10) in the network and both computers having one extra NIC card too.
I wanted to route traffic between A & B through an extra nic card, without affecting or using main network and onboard NIC.

Comment: You may have better luck on serverfault.com or hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you will use a different subnet for "extra" cards than for your "normal" cards then if you try to reach the other machine with that "extra" IP then the traffic will go through the "extra" interface.

So let's say your original network is 192.168.0.0/24 and your machines have IP from this network, 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2

You have to assign IP addresses from a different network let's say from 192.168.100.0/24 to the extra cards, 192.168.100.1 and 192.168.100.2

And now if you try to reach the IP 192.168.100.2 from 192.168.100.1 then the traffic will go through the "extra" interface.

Comment: Hello sir,

Thanks for the solution I kept Ip's as per suggestion but still data traffic use both NIC cards for sending receving data.

Comment: Are you sure your application uses the extra IP?

Comment: you can check the traffic with Wireshark